# Deployment to heroku failed while pip installing requirements using @

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, pip, requirements.txt

Using `virtualenv`, I'm developing a Dash/Python app. After adding a new package, I ran

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

and then tried to push the new changes to the linked Heroku server using git. Before this comment, the previous version on the server was running without an error.

While Heroku used `pip` to install the required packages listed in `requirements.txt` in the process of deployment, there was a failure.

> -----> Installing requirements with pip
>
> ...
>
> Processing /opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/976f8942-f51d-4f0e-7352-2a10f0820d0e/volume/cffi_1625814703974/work
>
> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] **No such file or directory**: '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/976f8942-f51d-4f0e-7352-2a10f0820d0e/volume/cffi_1625814703974/work'

In `requirements.txt`, the corresponding package appears as:

```
cffi @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/976f8942-f51d-4f0e-7352-2a10f0820d0e/volume/cffi_1625814703974/work
```

I googled but could not find any information about the use of **@** in `requirements.txt`. This is the first one that has @ link in the list and pip failed there, so this is suspicious.

Does anyone know what this @ means (I guess it means a link to a remote file), and how I can fix the push failure?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+freeze+weird

Answer (score -1):

I still can't tell what @ marks are, but for my second or more practical question of how to fix the issue, I found out what went wrong. And I can guess something about @ marks.

In short, without realising, it seemed that I once ran `pip freeze > requirements.txt` outside of my virtual environment. So there were way more packages than necessary in `requirements.txt` and that's essentially why `pip` on Heroku failed.

I suspect that the @ marks were given to packages that were installed outside of `pip`. Why instead of something like,

```
cffi # installed outside of pip!
```

, `pip` gives weird URLs, where are they from, or are they actually functional? I don't know.

In some cases, replacing the bit with `@ file://xxxxx` with version numbers like `==4.5.5` that are determined by `pip show <packagename>` helped. But interestingly, `pip` on Heroku could not install `conda`. This is when I wondered why on earth my project needed `conda`.